# How do I make R working with encoded files?

Tags: r, windows, encoding, utf-8

I'm strugling in finding a solution for an encoding problem I'm experiencing using R and windows.
Here is the problem:

1. I download excel files from internet including non-latin characters and save them as CSV. When I open this files with a mac I can properly see all the characters, with windows I get the 4-digit encoding or "?"
2. some of this characters are encoded when read in R, some no
3. Consequently a left_join doesn't work for those words including those characters.

I'd like to see on my pc the files as I see them with a mac and more importantly I need at least a consistency in R.
I've tried to set everthing to UTF-8 but with no results.
Any idea?

Thanks

Hereafter a minimal sample of the code. Being unable to attach the .csv I added a short sample at the end. Hope it's enough to undestand the problem.

```
 library(readr)
 sample1= read_csv("sample1.csv")
 sample2= read_csv("sample2.csv")     
 join = left_join(sample1,sample2 , by = "ColumnA")

###### sample 1.csv################
###### ColumnA
###### Walter Ben��tez
###### Xaver Schlager

###### sample 2.csv################
###### ColumnA
###### Walter Ben��tez
###### Paulo Ot��vio
```

Comment: Unicode in R on Windows is a nightmare… Please share a [mcve] (sanitizing your data sample).

Comment: Have you tried reading the Excel files directly with, for example, `readxl`?

Comment: Yes, please include some sample data if possible, or a link to the file you are interested in.  Also we'll need to see the R code you are reading the files in with.